# Why can I install NuGet v4.0.10 in VS2019 but not in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, npgsql

I want to get Npgsql for a project targeting .Net 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012.  It appears the latest Npgsql version supporting that version of .Net is 4.0.10.  In Visual Studio 2012, with package source set to nuget.org, I got the following:

```
PM> Install-Package Npgsql -Version 4.0.10
Install-Package : Unable to find version '4.0.10' of package 'Npgsql'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Npgsql -Version 4.0.10
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

But in Visual Studio 2019, with the same source, the package was installed successfully.  What do I have to do to install it in my VS2012 project?

Comment: Simply because Microsoft abandoned VS2012. You will have to upgrade to VS2017/2019, or install packages from command line.

Comment: No.  I haven't retried it.  I've got an older version of Npgsql I can use instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful response!  It has been accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in Visual Studio 2019, with the same source, the package was
>   installed successfully. What do I have to do to install it in my
>   VS2012 project?

**First**, thanks to **Lex** for sharing the useful info with us.

Since **VS2012** is too old to maintain it, the highest version of **Nuget** in **VS2012** is `v2.8.60318.667`. And `Npgsql 4.0.10` needs nuget `v4.xxx` or above which is not supported in **VS2012**.

[image]

[image]

**Solution**

If you want to install this nuget package in VS2012, you cannot install the latest version(4.0.10) of the **Npgsql** nuget package, you should install the version which nuget `v2.8.60318.667` supports.

And `Npgsql 3.1.10` is supported in **VS2012** which l have tested successfully.

**1)** If the nuget version in **VS2012** is not the latest, you should update nuget version to the latest `v2.8.60318.667`. (`Tools`-->`Extensions and Updates`-->`Updates`)

**2)** Open **Package Manage Console** by `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console` and type this:

```
Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.1.10
```

**Update**

Just install an old version of **Npgsql** (<=`3.1.10`)

Hope it could help you.